# Node JS - How do I add a delay between each retry

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    let tries = 1
while (true) {
  tries++

  if (tries > 5) {
    break
  }
  let keyword = encodeURIComponent(k)

  let itemid = itemids[itemidIndex]
  console.log(`Currently ${ki} of ${keywords.length} item id ${itemid}`)

  let url = `https://URL=0`

  let resp = await singleBrowserRequest(page, {
    url,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "GET",
  })

  if (resp.includes(`invalid item id`)) {
    console.log("ERROR on item id", resp)
    itemidIndex = (itemidIndex + 1) % itemids.length
    break
  }

  try {
    let respJson = JSON.parse(resp)
    for (let info of respJson.data) {
      data[info.keyword] = info
    }
    break
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error on", url, resp, "end")
  }
}
```

}

Hi guys, would like to add a delay of 10 secs on error on each retry how can I do that?

Not very sure with the coding so if any help can be offered it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

If the function this code is called in is `async` (e.g. `async function fn() {` instead of `function fn() {` you can pause for `10` seconds with this code:

```js
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10_000));
```

For example:

```js
async function fn() {
  while (true) {
    console.log('foo');
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1_000));
  }
}

fn();
```